# How to define an explicit bijection from P(N) to 2^N

Tags: analysis, cardinals

How do I define an explicit bijection between the power set of N and $2^N$ with $2^N =\{f|f:N\to\{0,1\} \text{ is a function} \}$?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: For a subset $A$ of $N$, take $f(x)=1$ iff $x\in A$.

Comment: no, it's an exercise in my textbook, and I can't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign to every subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, the map 
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\chi_S \colon \mathbb{N} &\to &\{0,1\}\\
x & \mapsto & \left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
1 \quad\text{ if } x\in S, \\
0 \quad\text{ if } x \notin S.
\end{array}
\right.
\end{array}
$$